# Wii widescreen doesn't appear to work

Tags: nintendo-wii

When I set my Wii to 16:9 it doesn't appear wide at all. It looked exactly the same and the menu looks like it is in 4:3. Maybe it looked a little zoomed out but the sides were not wide.

Pressing 'info' on my TV said the signal was 480i and "SD" (standard definition). Going into other Wii options I see 480p is not available. I don't know what happens if my TV gets a 480p signal but iIdo know it supports 1080p.

What's with this widescreen business and 480p thing?

Comment: Have you changed the aspect ratio of the TV to the 16:9 or widescreen setting (using the TV remote)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the proper output cable to get 480p.  If memory serves, you need to use **component output**.  Out of the box, the Wii comes with a composite output cable.  **You'll need to purchase a separate Wii component output cable.**

[From Nintendo's product page:](http://store.nintendo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=117711)

> The Wii Component Video Cable allows you to hook your Wii console system to a high-definition TV (HDTV) or enhanced-definition TV (EDTV) to view 480p progressive output. 480p progressive output displays at a higher resolution than standard 480i resolution....
>
> Please note that your TV must be a high-definition TV (HDTV) or enhanced-definition TV (EDTV) to view 480p output. You will also be required to change your Wii settings from Standard TV (480i) to EDTV/HDTV to view 480p....
>
> You cannot see Wii progressive display output when the Wii console system is hooked to a TV using any other kind of cable.

Comment: ah ha thanks. Its... nonsense that in that year they would only support 480p. 720p i may consider it if the cables are cheap enough but wow this is underwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

The Wii uses analog video signals.  To my knowledge, analog signals do not carry information about whether the signal is standard definition or widescreen.

This means you have to change the settings on your TV for that channel to widescreen.

As for the cable, Widescreen may only work with component cables as splattered bits already mentioned.  Even if it isn't, the system will not support progressive scan mode without it.